# Mixed Return Values

Tags: cakephp-2.3

In the CakePHP API when the return value is mixed, does that mean to returns different in the contexted its used? For example, if used in a logical setting like:

```
if($this->save())
```

it would return true or false, but if use in an assignment situation:

```
$data = $this->save();
```

it would return the data being saved?

Reference: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PHP` if a method returns a `mixed` type it means that it can return different types of variables depending on the input, not the context in which it is called. In your example it will return `Model::$data` (when populated) or `true` (when it is not) on success, or `false` on error.

Because `true` and a non null object value will evaluate to `true` in `PHP`, you can implement your example like:

```
$data = $this->save();
if ($data===true){
   // save() was successful, and $data is the boolean true
} elseif ($data) {
   // save() was successful, and $data is the object Model::$data
} else {
   // save() failed.
}
```

This is all possible because `PHP` is not strongly typed like languages such as `Java` and `C` which expect variables and method return types to be explicitly defined.